# Optimisation to minimse distance between nearest neighbours Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, function, optimization, minimization

I have identified nearest neighbours amongst a population. I wish to assign a vector of weights to the population such that the difference in weights between nearest neighbours is minimised via an optimisation. I have built:

```
fun=@(x)sum(nthroot(x-logicalmatrix*x),2)
A=ones(1,height(Population));
b=1;
Aeq=A;
beq=1; % Solution should sum to 1
lb=zeros(height(Population),1); % Lower Bounds
ub=ones(height(Population),1); % UpperBounds
[opt_combinedfun,~,residualCombfun]=fmincon(fun,lb,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,[],options);
```

However, although sometimes it returns a solution within bounds it does not appear optimal. The '*logicalmatrix*' is a *n x n* logical matrix identifying the nearest neighbours. The problem is that *logicalmatrix* is singular which causes the optimisation to return:

> Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled.
>   Results may be inaccurate.

is fmincon the wrong function to use? Or is there a way to get around the singularity? A more robust way to achieve this optimisation?

Comment: I don't get the point of your calculation ...  Why not assigning similar weigths to all nodes ? All differences would be 0s ...

Comment: Yes, excellent point, and I agree- you would expect the optimisation as written above to give that as a solution, but it does not! The function is a little more complex than the one stated (it has a linear least squares part which tries to match attributes of the individuals) hence the weights will not be equal in a successful optimisation. The LLS part works fine and for brevity I have just given the part of the function that is the problem.